# Dependency can not be found in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have an multiple modules gradle project:

```
app
    app-libs
    app-support
    app-main
```

*app-support/build.gradle:*

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir dirs: 'D:\\docs\\development\\java\\tools\\proguard4.11\\lib'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ':proguard:'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir:"${rootDir}/app-libs/esri",include:['*.jar'])
}
task myProguardTask(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    configuration 'proguard-rules.txt'
}
```

*app-main/build.gradle:*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile project(':app-support')
}
```

Now, when I run `gradlew build`, it throw errors during building the `app-main` module, which said the classes defined in the app-libs/esri/xx.jars can not be found.

What's the problem?

---

```
gradlw build > log.txt
```

Generate logs like this:

```
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:app-main:compileDebugNdk
:app-support:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:preBuild
:app-main:preDebugBuild
:app-main:checkDebugManifest
:app-main:preReleaseBuild
:app-main:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:classes UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:jar UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:test UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71901Library UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:check UP-TO-DATE
:app-support:build UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:prepareDebugDependencies
:app-main:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app-main:compileDebugJava FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.577 secs
```

And error in the console:

```
D:\workspace\app\app-main\src\main\java\com\api\test\MainActivity.java:9: Error: Package com.esri.android.map does not exist
```

Comment: Please post the full exact error message, including its context (to see which task fails).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser:I update the question and post the full message.

Comment: Looks like the code in `app-main` makes use of the `app-libs/esri` Jars without `app-main/build.gradle` declaring them as a dependency. Have you tried to fix this?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: Yes, I do not add the jars in `app-main/build.gradle`, but I add them in the `app-support/build.gradle`, while the `app-main` depend on `app-support`, so it it necessary to add them twice?

Comment: You should always model the actual direct dependencies of the code, and not rely on them being pulled in transitively. I'm not sure if it will solve the problem, but it's worth a try.